# How would I strip out comments from a file with Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have this much:

```
comment :: GenParser Char st ()
comment =
    (string "--" >> manyTill anyChar newline >> spaces >> return ()) <|>
    (string "/*" >> manyTill anyChar (string "*/") >> spaces >> return ())

eatComments :: GenParser Char st String
eatComments = do
  xs <- many (do
          optional comment
          x <- manyTill anyChar (try comment)
          return x)
  return $ intercalate " " xs
```

This works if the input ends with a comment, but it fails if it ends with something else. In that case the error message is like

```
No match (line 13, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting "--" or "/*"
```

So the parser is looking for a comment by the time `eof` arrives. I need some help finding the right combinators I need to eat up all the comments in all possible cases.

Comment: If you don't want to preserve comments, use the Token module. See the examples in the original Parsec 2.0 distribution for use of the Token module and LanguageDef's: http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/parsec.html

Comment: Does that require a language def for MySQL's version of SQL and DDL?

Comment: Yes. Effectively a LangaugeDef is a lexer specification for Parsec. They are much simpler to write than an Alex lexer - though they are less powerful.

Comment: Do you know if anyone has written one for MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Through a bit of Googling I found this HPaste: http://hpaste.org/76009 - following the links at the bottom it seems to be authored by Chris Doner, though I'm not sure as I don't know how HPaste "works". Chris is often on the Haskell Reddit, so you could try asking there.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful even for study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use something like [eof](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3aeof) ?

```
comment :: GenParser Char st ()
comment =
    (string "--" >> manyTill anyChar newline >> spaces >> return ()) <|>
    (string "/*" >> manyTill anyChar ((try (string "*/") >> return ()) <|> eof) >> spaces >> return ())
```

Comment: For me that produces the error "Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `()'"

Comment: ... In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely `eof'
    In the second argument of `manyTill', namely
      `(string "*/" <|> eof)'

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. Also, please note that you need something like `try (string "*/")` to close the comment, otherwise the following input will fail: /* Hello World **/

Answer (score 0):

I hit on this which seems to work. But please feel free to critique:

```
comment :: GenParser Char st ()
comment =
    (string "--" >> manyTill anyChar newline >> spaces >> return ()) <|>
    (string "/*" >> manyTill anyChar (string "*/") >>  spaces >> return ())

notComment = manyTill anyChar (lookAhead (comment <|> eof))

eatComments :: GenParser Char st String
eatComments = do
  optional comment
  xs <- sepBy notComment comment
  optional comment
  return $ intercalate "" xs
```