# Parsing data with Parsec and omitting comments

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am trying to write a Haksell Parsec Parser that parses input data from a file into the LogLine datatype as follows:

```
--Final parser that holds the indvidual parsers.
final :: Parser [LogLine]
final = do{ logLines <- sepBy1 logLine eol
        ; return logLines
        }


--The logline token declaration
logLine :: Parser LogLine
logLine = do
name <-  plainValue -- parse the name (identifier)
many1 space -- parse and throw away a space
args1 <- bracketedValue -- parse the first arguments
many1 space -- throw away the second sapce
args2 <- bracketedValue -- parse the second list of arguments
many1 space -- 
constant <- plainValue -- parse the constant identifier
space
weighting <- plainValue --parse the weighting double
space
return $ LogLine name args1 args2 constant weighting
```

It parses everything just fine, but now I need to add comments to the file, and I have to modify the parser so that it ignores them.
It should support single-line comments only beginning with "--" and ending with a '\n'
I've tried defining the comment token as follows:

```
comments :: Parser String
comments = do 
    string "--"
    comment <- (manyTill anyChar newline)
    return ""
```

And then plugging it into the `final` parser like so:

```
final :: Parser [LogLine]
final = do 
        optional comments
        logLines <- sepBy1 logLine (comments<|>newline)
        optional comments
        return logLines
```

It compiles fine, but it does not parse. I've tried several minor modifications but the best result was parsing everything up to the first comment, so I'm beginning to think that this is not the way to do it.
PS:
I've seen this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940490/how-would-i-strip-out-comments-from-a-file-with-parsec), but it is slightly different from what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I suspect that at least part of your problem is that `logLine` requires exactly one space before and after `weighting`. Depending on your format, making them consume any amount of spaces (`' '` only or all whitespace) may be the way to go. The separator could then be `optional comments` or `comments <|> fmap return newline` (Note: `comments <|> newline` shouldn't compile since `comments` returns `[Char]` and `newline` a `Char`.)

Comment: Okay the format of the input file is such that on each row you have either a logLine or a comment, you can't have more than one of them on the same line. Something like this:
`name arg1 arg2 c1 weight
 --comment goes here. 
 name2 arg1 arg2 c2 weight2`
I know that requiring the extra space after the weight is alogical, but if I remove it, it doesn't parse for whatever reason.
Something that I want to ask you, when you're saying the _separator_
do you mean that I should define a new separator or just do something like:
`logLines <- sepBy1 (logLine) (comments <|> fmap return newline)`

Comment: Sorry the newlines didn't come up. The example should have been as so:
name arg1 arg2 c1 weight \n
--comment goes here.\n
name2 arg1 arg2 c2 weight2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your description of the format in your comment correctly, your example for the format would be

```
name arg1 arg2 c1 weight
-- comment goes here
```

optionally followed by further log-lines and/or comments.

Then your problem is that there is a newline between the log-line and the comment line, which means that the `comments` part of the separator parser fails - `comments` must start with `"--"` - without consuming input, so `newline` is tried and succeeds. Then the next line begins with `"--"` which makes `plainValue` fail without consuming input, and thus ends the `sepBy1`.

The solution is to let the separator first consume a newline, and then as many comment lines as follow:

```
final = do
    skipMany comments
    sepEndBy1 logLine (newline >> skipMany comments)
```

by allowing the sequence to be ended by a separator (`sepEndBy1` instead of `sepBy1`), any comment lines after the final `LogLine` are automatically skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand your problem, each line is either a comment or a logLine. If so, `final` should look something like this:

```
final :: Parser [LogLine]
final = do 
        logLines <- sepBy1 (comment<|>logLine) newline
        return logLines
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but the thing is that `sepBy1` will only take the same type of datatype to parse. 
So this is not going to work because comment is a `Char` and logLine a `logLine`

Comment: I would simply add a value for comments to LogLine and filter those out. But if you don't want to do that, using this should also work: `lines <- endBy logLine (many1 $ comments<|>string "\n")`